Implementing sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor with sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor and sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV
I'm trying to create models that support multivariate output. One of the models I'm trying to use is the GradientBoostingRegressor which does not natively support multivariate output. There is a workaround by using MultiOutputRegressor which provides this functionality via a "wrapper" of some sort. Unfortunately, that wrapping does not work when trying to do hyperparameter tuning using RandomizedSearchCV.
The following works:
model_gradboost = MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42))
model_gradboost.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_gradboost = model_gradboost.predict(X_test)

But the following does not
gradboost_n_estimators = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
gradboost_max_depth = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
gradboost_eta = [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.012, 0.16]
gradboost_max_features = ["sqrt", "log2", None]
gradboost_alpha = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
gradboost_subsample = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
gradboost_loss = ["squared_error", "absolute_error", "huber", "quantile"]

gradboost_dict_params = {
      "n_estimators": gradboost_n_estimators
    , "max_depth": gradboost_max_depth
    , "learning_rate": gradboost_eta
    , "max_features": gradboost_max_features
    , "alpha": gradboost_alpha
    , "subsample": gradboost_subsample
    , "loss": gradboost_loss
}

model_gradboost = MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=42))
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_gradboost, param_distributions=gradboost_dict_params, n_iter=200, cv=5, scoring='r2', return_train_score=True)
random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

and causes an error, namely:
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'subsample' for estimator MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=42)). Valid parameters are: ['estimator', 'n_jobs'].

How can I get around this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Solution found. I believe you can do it one of two ways, although only the first method ran to completion while testing (I aborted the 2nd method while it was running even though it didn't give any errors for the hour or so it did run).
Method 1
Credit for this solution
Create your parameter dictionary using keys that don't exactly match the expected hyperparameter names, but which are prefixed by test "model__estimator__" i.e.
# Different values for selected hyperparameters
gradboost_n_estimators = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
gradboost_max_depth = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
gradboost_eta = [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.012, 0.16]
gradboost_max_features = ["sqrt", "log2", None]
gradboost_alpha = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
gradboost_subsample = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
gradboost_loss = ["squared_error", "absolute_error", "huber", "quantile"]

gradboost_dict_params = {
    #  "n_estimators": gradboost_n_estimators
    #, "max_depth": gradboost_max_depth
    #, "learning_rate": gradboost_eta
    #, "max_features": gradboost_max_features
    #, "alpha": gradboost_alpha
    #, "subsample": gradboost_subsample
    #, "loss": gradboost_loss

      "model__estimator__n_estimators": gradboost_n_estimators
    , "model__estimator__max_depth": gradboost_max_depth
    , "model__estimator__learning_rate": gradboost_eta
    , "model__estimator__max_features": gradboost_max_features
    , "model__estimator__alpha": gradboost_alpha
    , "model__estimator__subsample": gradboost_subsample
    , "model__estimator__loss": gradboost_loss    
}

Then when creating your model, use:
model_gradboost = Pipeline(
    steps = [("model", MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=42)))]
)
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model_gradboost, param_distributions=params, n_iter=150, cv=5, scoring='r2', return_train_score=True)

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
# etc.

Method 2
Use the conventional method to create your param dictionary
gradboost_n_estimators = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
gradboost_max_depth = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
gradboost_eta = [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.012, 0.16]
gradboost_max_features = ["sqrt", "log2", None]
gradboost_alpha = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
gradboost_subsample = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
gradboost_loss = ["squared_error", "absolute_error", "huber", "quantile"]

gradboost_dict_params = {
      "n_estimators": gradboost_n_estimators
    , "max_depth": gradboost_max_depth
    , "learning_rate": gradboost_eta
    , "max_features": gradboost_max_features
    , "alpha": gradboost_alpha
    , "subsample": gradboost_subsample
    , "loss": gradboost_loss
}

but when creating the model, use a different sequence for nesting the function calls, i.e.
model_gradboost = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=42)
random_search = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomizedSearchCV(model_gradboost, param_distributions=params, n_iter=200, cv=5, scoring='r2', return_train_score=True))

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
# etc.

Basically, the MultiOutputRegressor must be the last stage and not an intermediate stage as I had been trying to do previously.
EDIT: In fact, while method 2 sort of works, the final object that result out of the nested calls is actually NOT a randomized search object, meaning we cannot use the properties of the RandomizedSearchCV class, such as best_estimator_ , best_score_ , best_params_ , best_index_ , etc. If you need to access those properties, you will need to use method 1.
